# Reputation does not match by events?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-summary

In my user account page, I analyzed my reputation total, and it didn't add up:

> [image: 50 total, net change of 49]

I think they should match. What's wrong? What am I missing?

> UPDATE: first time of downvote cast for me !!

After casting downvote , my reputation was descreased as my downvote casted. But there has nothing showing. I think that may differ reputation. Am I right ?

Comment: I think the error you are seeing (which isn't really an error) is because you start at 1 not 0

Comment: @John Palmer, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: see michaelb's answer -but basically 1+49=50

Comment: @Cataclysm - Are you talking about your Meta profile? Where did you downvote? (i.e. on question or on answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine. If I add up the changes displayed, and add your 1 starting reputation, I get 50.

```
  1     - 3
+15     -10
+ 2     ===
+44     -13
+ 1
===
+63

63 - 13 = 50
```

Comment: Now , I understand. Thanks sir.