# How can I edit my question to make it "active" without taking credit from a previous editor?

Tags: discussion, edits, bump

I asked a question with bad grammar and poor quality because I have poor English skills. Another experienced user edited my question. I really appreciated his editing and am very grateful to him.

But one day later, my question is not on the "Active" list. I would like my question to still appear active, so I edited it. The question lost the previous ***question editor***. My question status has changed to active and shows it was **edited by me** just a few seconds ago.

I don't want this because I assume the previous question editor has lost some reputation.  How can I make my question active without losing the previous question editor? I know I could add a bounty, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Editing may become adding a single space... without changing any statements.

Comment: Your edit will not revoke the `+2` reputation from the previous user who suggested an edit(if below 2k and didn't accumulate `1000` rep from edits yet). In case it was a user higher than 2k reputation, the user would have never got any reputation for the edit, so there is nothing to lose at all.

Comment: @R.J Can I read any messages about with it ? Has any link for it ?

Comment: I think you may want to read this, [How do suggested edits work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/216721).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you mean [this question of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204513/reputation-does-not-match-by-events)?

> [image]

No worry, the previous edit is kept safely in the [revisions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/204513/revisions), just one click away: (on the "edited" part)

> [image]

The editor's reputation is also safe, once his edit was approved he got +2 and it's taken back only if the post is deleted.

Bottom line: edit at will, you will appear as the last editor but all previous editors still have their place of honor.

Comment: Cheers @Cat, just familiar with the system, no additional eyes here... ;)

Comment: @michaelb958 [here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SGk7X.png), keep it in a safe! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It doesn't *feel* like that recently that I had to suggest edits...

Answer (score 10):

You are indicating a behavior that is not exactly welcomed in SO:
Do **not** suggest minute (small) edits just to "bump up" your question in the "Active" list.

However, if you have a **real** edit to make you can just do it -- you need not fear for previous users who edited your question, because:

1. You can always see "edit history" of each post (the "edited XX ago" is actually a link to the post's revisions).
2. If any reps were earned by the previous user who edted your post - these reps stays with him/her and he will not loose them. See R.J's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209714/how-to-do-my-question-to-active-without-changing-editor#comment671592_209714).